Enable xml files in outlook OWA 365 or New Outlook
I tried to follow the answer here: Enable xml files in outlook owa, however it seems to be obsolete these days.
We are using a common mailbox which receives only .xml files, and we have to keep using old Outlook application to open them, otherwise both new outlook nor OWA blocks them.
So following the answer, particularly this:
$cred = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $session

I get error 500 on New-PSSession, so I tried this:
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName 

But then can't use command Get-OwaMailboxPolicy listed in the answer, nor any Get-MailboxPolicy, so I can't run those:
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -BlockedFileTypes @{Remove = ".xml"}
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -AllowedFileTypes @{Add = ".xml"}
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -BlockedMimeTypes @{Remove = "text/xml", "application/xml"}
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy –AllowedMimeTypes @{Add = "text/xml", "application/xml"}

In Exchange administration pages, we found this 2 entries:

Safe attachments - https://security.microsoft.com/safeattachmentv2
Safe links - https://security.microsoft.com/safelinksv2

However it requires activating premium feature M365 Defender. Question is, if we activate it, can we configure attachments so that we can open .XML files as before?
Any help would be appreciated.

Not really. New Outlook does not currently support .xml files. But on OWA, you can open it by command.
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy |Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -BlockedFileTypes @{Remove = “.xml”}
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy |Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -AllowedFileTypes @{Add = “.xml”}
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy |Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -BlockedMimeTypes @{Remove = “text/xml”， “application/xml”}
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy |Set-OwaMailboxPolicy –AllowedMimeTypes @{Add = “text/xml”， “application/xml”}

Another way is by compressing the file and then sending it by mail. Then I found that after switching to New Outlook, I can start searching for the classic version, and both versions can exist at the same time.
Also, I feel like this is a nice feature that can be added through feedback channels. I've already submitted this feedback before.

Thanks for your reply, however I'm unable to run Get-OwaMailboxPolicy commands ? Searching for a solution to that, I got the Get-Credential / New-PSSession, however the second command returns error 500!
